# heroku rake db:migrate, rake aborted! undefined method 'task'

Tags: heroku, rake, dbmigrate

When i run:
heroku rake db:migrate,

I get this error message:

```
 rake aborted!
 undefined method 'task' for #<'Myapp::Application:0x7f07c011f4f8>
```

I'm running rake 0.8.7 and have uninstalled rake 0.9.

Also, when i add --trace, these files come up:

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb
```

(sorry for not being exact, I can't copy n paste, I'm running windows)

So, im guessin the rake-0.9.0 file that comes up is the culprit :S, but i
dunno how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the exact version of rake in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
```

This won't work if you have any dependencies relying on rake 0.9, of course.

Comment: i've already added gem 'rake, '0.8.7' to my Gemfile and ran bundle install and it said rake 0.8.7 was installed.